# CCScale not working on sprite

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to scale my sprite using CCScaleTo.

Here is my code :

```
CCSprite *spritePauseScreen =[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"resumeGameScreenBG.png"] ;
spritePauseScreen.position= ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2);
spritePauseScreen.scale=0.5f;
[spritePauseScreen runAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.6 scaleX:1.0f scaleY:1.0f]];
[self addChild:spritePauseScreen z:7];
```

Its not working. The sprite is shown on scale value of 0.5 only. It does not get scaled up to 1.0 Please help?...

Comment: Now I used same code in Cocos2D 2.0 sample, Its working fine. May be problem with your base layer?

Comment: Really thanks Raj for the concern. It was my bad. I was using this animation for the pause screen pop up. So the mistake was that i was doing ,[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause]; at the same time due to which game engine stopped performing any action.

Any wayz. Reali thanks for the help. :)

Comment: You got right reason, that's great. Welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Try This Code.

```
int delayTime = 0.3f;
CCSprite *each = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon.png"];
each.position = ccp(160,240);
each.scaleX = 0.0f;
each.scaleY = 0.0f;
CCAction *action = [CCSequence actions:
          [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration: delayTime],
          [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5F scale:1.0],nil];
delayTime += 0.2f;
[each runAction: action];
[self addChild:each];
```

Comment: Hi Femina. Reali thanks for the concern. Your code was correct. It was my bad. I was using this animation for the pause screen pop up. So the mistake was that i was doing ,[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause]; at the same time due to which game engine stopped performing any action. Any wayz. Reali thanks for the help. :)